# iOS - Facebook pop framework - Repeat forever "shake" animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, facebook-pop

I'm using Facebook pop framework to perform some cool animations. I'm shaking a button in this way :

```
let rotation = POPSpringAnimation.init(propertyNamed: kPOPLayerRotation)
rotation.springBounciness = 30
rotation.springSpeed = 20
rotation.velocity = 30.0
rotation.repeatForever = true

button.layer.pop_addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "rotation")
```

Despite of the `repeatForever` set to `true` the animation doesn't repeat. I noticed that if we have the `toValue` property set, the animation repeats. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `POPBasicAnimation`. If you're rotating forever, you may not need the spring animation.

Looking at your code, you don't have a `rotation.toValue` You need to tell the animation how far to rotate. Try this:

```
func configureBtnRotation(btn: UIButton) {
  let rotation = POPBasicAnimation(propertyNamed: kPOPLayerRotation)
  rotation.toValue = 90.0
  rotation.duration = 100.0 //this sets the speed of rotation
  rotation.repeatForever = true
  button.layer.pop_addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "rotation")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue adding the following:

`rotation.fromValue = 0.0`